# Alpine flower with yellow blossoms?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers, alpine

A friend found a yellow flower in her garden in the French Alps, at 1000 m altitude, above Evian:

[image: Unknown yellow flower]

What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Lysimachia punctata, common name Loosestrife, so not exactly a wildflower - it is an herbaceous perennial which is widespread throughout Europe, including the UK, and, if grown in a dampish spot, can be highly invasive.

http://www.aphotoflora.com/d_lysimachia_punctata_dotted_loosestrife.html

Comment: Bamboo, was Lysimachia once Lythrum?  Gee I always had the two combined...what I do know they are both incredibly prolific and our Purple Loosestrife is the top of the baddest weeds list...Lythrum salicaria.  Beautiful plant and that is why it got brought over from where ever.  Millions of seeds per flower or something like that.  Very bad for our wetlands.  And I have found Purple Loosestrife in almost every nursery I've walked into...the same exact brand.

Comment: @stormy Nope, not even vaguely related - Lysimachia belongs to Primulaceae and Lythrum to Lythraceae. It;ll be the common name of loosestrife that's caused confusion - just as common names  unfailingly do... and is precisely why I loathe and detest them. Who needs language barriers when common plant names do the job just as well...